# Проверка на сервере

Tags: php

Как лучше всего на сервере проверить и обезвредить данные введенные пользователем, если это текс сообщения и там могут присутствовать как буквы русские, английские и цифры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Об этом уже не раз говорилось:

```
$text = stripslashes($text); // Удаляет экранирование символов
$text = htmlspecialchars($text); // Преобразует специальные символы в HTML-сущности
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text); // Экранирует специальные символы в строках для использования в выражениях SQL
```

Comment: а какой смысл убирать слеши, ели ты уже убрал HtML теги ?

Comment: А где у меня сказанно, что надо использовать все функции сразу? Это раз. А во вторых, если допускается, что пользователь может в сообшении писать код (как тут на hashcode), то это stripslashes необходим для корректного отображения кода.

Answer (score 0):

$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
 функция, результат которой бывает виден типа: &qout;Smith&amp;Wesson&qout;
хотя & и " экранировать и не надо было. Обратно-то как? :)

Надо было поставить точно задачу - а ДЛЯ ЧЕГО именно обезвредить данные?
если для записи в базу - хватит и mysql _ real _ escape _ string($text), которая уберет '

если для безопасного вывода обратно в браузер (в форум например) - то стоит озаботиться вырезанием тэгов strip_tags()